# Simulator/Device name shows only Unity-iPhone

Tags: ios7, unity-game-engine, xcode5

Just loaded a project in Unity 3D (4.34f) it is working as desired, Built and Run for iOS devices. works perfect in the Xcode (5.1.1) simulator.
In the Simulator/Device Name is written Unity-iPhone, it does not show neither my iPad or my iphone when connected.
What am I missing? any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, happens to me frequently, two choices deselect the Development Build in build settings or in the player settings change the dropdown list of Optimization SDK Version to "Device SDK".
Let me know if works for you....

Comment: Great I did not realize this option about SDK Version thanks Jade.